# Flutter - Overlay a widget inside another stack

Tags: flutter, widget, overlap

Say I have a `container2`, and a stack whose children are `[container1, container3]`, how can I make the overlay look like `[container1, container2, container3]` such that `container2` is occluded by only some children in the stack? Because the stack is wrapped by other widgets, e.g., Transform, I can't simply insert `container2` into that stack.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: sorry, you cannot do that

Comment: Can you post your widget code and/or a screenshot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.